# Update image on button VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image, button, bmp

I’m trying to make a button that displays an image, that’s easy, but the image is an editable icon so I want the image on the button to be updated every time the form is started how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making the assumption that you are using WinForms and saving your editied icon to a file.

Take a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx#Y0) page on  `ButtonBase.Image` Property.

From above link:

```
button1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Graphics\MyBitmap.bmp")
```

You can put this in the New Subroutine after the InitializeComponent Statement. or in your Form Load event.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Graphics` method and also handle the `Paint` event of Button. You can add text and primitive drawing on Image or Button region.